# The jump link in WeChat , this parameter '#wechat_redirect' is always intercepted, causing no jump

Tags: javascript, wechat

The jump link in WeChat is "https://mp.weixin.qq.com/bizmall/activatemembercard?action=preshow&encrypt_card_id=KtD1tYmjM032MdW%2Fa%2FS2VseLRX%2Bsqont0weFhI8kdSlKWqXZoaXK0Hg8W30DmU5F&outer_str=rostest2&biz=MzI4MjM4MjE4NA%3D%3D#wechat_redirect"，But this paramete[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZ0Ch.jpg)r '#wechat_redirect'  is always intercepted, causing no jump

Comment: Can you post some more detail about your problem? What is your expected behaviour? What does `intercepted` mean?

Answer (score 0):

The jump link in WeChat is "https://mp.weixin.qq.com/bizmall/activatemembercard?action=preshow&encrypt_card_id=KtD1tYmjM032MdW%2Fa%2FS2VseLRX%2Bsqont0weFhI8kdSlKWqXZoaXK0Hg8W30DmU5F&outer_str=rostest2&biz=MzI4MjM4MjE4NA%3D%3D#wechat_redirect"，But the parameter'#wechat_redirect' is always intercepted, causing no jump

Comment: Please don't repeat your question in answer.